# Custom URL for https urls in Community

Tags: community, force.com-sites

I am trying to do a setup for custom URL for salesforce community.
I created a CName record and mapped it to proper site.
Its working fine for all HTTP URL.
But after a user get logged-in to the community portal , its URL is changing from HTTP to HTTPS and from that point the custom URL is not working.
And I can see the force.com in my community URL.

Please suggest how I can achieve the custom URL for HTTPS URL in community.

Comment: Only domains that don’t point to the yourdomain.your18characterOrgId.live.siteforce.com CNAME target have this option available. See [Managing Domains and Custom URLs](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=domain_mgmt_dom_detail.htm&language=en_US).

Answer (score 2):

There are a few steps in addition to having the CNAME on Salesforce side in order to get everything to work right. You have to create the private key, then use that to generate a certificate request file, then purchase a CA signed SSL cert, upload that to salesforce, then configure your community to use the custom domain.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_communities_implementation.meta/salesforce_communities_implementation/communities_custom_domain_URL.htm